# Warning when archiving product in Xcode with AppIntent extension

Tags: xcode, cocoa

When building my app for debugging in Xcode I don't get any warning, only when archiving the product:

```
MyIntent.appex is an ExtensionKit extension and must be embedded in the parent app bundle's Extensions directory, but is embedded in the parent app bundle's ../../../BuildProductsPath/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/Extensions directory.
```

The `MyIntent.appex` is listed in the main target's `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content` section and its Build Phase `Embed ExtensionKit Extensions` with Destination `ExtensionKit Extensions`. The extension also seems to work, since the app intent is correctly listed in the Shortcuts app.

Is this an Xcode bug or do I need to do something different?

Comment: I also get this error and currently can't find a way to fix it. Also the shortcut extension currently does not work under macOS Sonoma. It says "Can't communicate with the app". It works pretty fine on Ventura.